# Table doesn't exist on CRE Loaded 6.2 install

Tags: php, xampp, oscommerce

I want to install CRE Loaded 6.2 on my local machine running XAMPP server but it's showing the following error:

> 1146 - Table 'creloader.configuration' doesn't exist
>   select configuration_key as cfgKey, configuration_value as cfgValue from configuration
>   TEP_DB_ERROR

What does it mean? I also created database named `creloader`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what is creloded6.2 but in all installation packages there is a sql file you have to run in your database, it seems you haven't done it.